# Artifactory Delay

Tags: pip, artifactory

As we noticed that with artifacts uploaded to Artifactory, they do not appear available via pip straight away. As minimum 5 minutes before they can be downloaded and installed via pip. It seems like they are not indexed straight away or waiting for some timeslot to do so. Could not find any configuration related to this which is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-speed-up-my-pypi-indexing/), which might be helpful to you:

> When you upload many Pypi packages to the same repository within a close period of time the indexing does not happen immediately. It waits for a "quiet period" which can be adjusted. This can be done in the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties` file by setting the values of the `artifactory.pypi.index.quietPeriodSecs` and the `artifactory.pypi.index.sleepMilliSecs` properties to an amount of seconds that meets your needs. If those parameters do not exist, please add them to the file. You will need to restart Artifactory for this setting to take affect.

From what I can tell, if these values aren't in that file, both default to `60`. Also `sleepMilliSecs` appears to be a number of seconds, not milliseconds as the name would suggest.

I believe how this works is, Artifactory waits for the repository to "settle", until there hasn't been any changes (deployed or removed packages) for at least `quietPeriodSecs` seconds. It will check for this every `sleepMilliSecs` seconds.

---

Five minutes seems like a long time. If you're making a series of changes with under a minute before each change, that might explain why it's taking a while. Also, the larger your repository is, the longer the indexing will take once it starts, so that might also be a factor.